# If $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$, is $-x$ also an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I am getting two different solutions for the eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue when using two different numeric methods. I believe I can say both are valid through the following logic:

$$
\lambda \mathbf{x}=A\mathbf{x}\\
\therefore -\lambda \mathbf{x}=-A\mathbf{x}\\
\therefore \lambda(-\mathbf{x})=A(-\mathbf{x})\\
$$

Hence, $-\mathbf{x}$ is also an eigenvector of $A$.

Am I thinking correctly? Can I make this conclusion? I couldn't find anything about this, probably because I don't know the search terms to use.

Comment: Yes. If $\textbf{x}$ is an eigenvector the $c\textbf{x}$ is also an eigenvector.

Comment: You may get two solution, because there may be two linearly independent eigenvector corresponds to same eigenvalue like Identity matrix.

Comment: @MadhanKumar: your first comment is only true for non-zero $c$. Your second comment is irrelevant.

Comment: Irrelevant in the sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Actually, any nonzero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is again an eigenvector. If $Av=\lambda v$ then for any $\mu\in \Bbb{R}$ with $\mu \ne 0$, $A(\mu v)=\mu Av=\mu \lambda v=\lambda\cdot\mu v$.

Answer (score 1):

The set of eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$ along with the zero vector constitute a vector space called the eigenspace. That is, the eigenvectors are closed under addition and scalar multiplication. You may refer to a linear algebra text to learn more about eigenvalues and eigenvectors.